# Why does react empty attributes when using a web component?

Tags: reactjs, web-component

I am pretty new to react and trying to use a web component in the template and there are is a thing i dont understand.

It can be seen in this example below if you run the page (may need to hit reload once). Then watch the console. You will see the log in the constructor() the outerHTML is not "ready" yet its missing all attributes in the markup and they arrive only later on (in the connectedCallback) which is the second log.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jcjuvs?file=App.tsx,index.tsx

Whats happening here? Is there anyway to force the attributes to be available initially? Or not taken off and then put back on?

Note that doing this in a normal page does not have the same effect.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-l4uh4f?file=index.js,index.html

a) whats happening?
b) can i make this not happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There no no guarantee that a web component will have access to attributes in the constructor and attribute values can change at anytime. You should use the [attributeChangedCallback lifecycle callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#using_the_lifecycle_callbacks) to know when values are set.

> The element's attributes and children must not be inspected, as in the non-upgrade case none will be present, and relying on upgrades makes the element less usable.
>
> [Requirements for custom element constructors and reactions](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance)

Comment: Attributes are available in the connectedCallback